# Does elastic beanstalk run the postinstall from a package.json file?

Tags: node.js, elastic-beanstalk

I am using elastic beanstalk to deploy a node.js app. In my `scripts` section of `package.json` I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/coffee server.coffee",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test node test/runner.js",
    "coverage": "NODE_ENV=test COVERAGE=1 node test/runner.js -R html-cov test/ > ./test/coverage.html",
    "testw": "fswatch -o test src | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'coffeelint src server.coffee ; npm test'",
    "db:drop": "node scripts/drop-tables.js",
    "encryptConfig": "node_modules/.bin/coffee config/encrypt.coffee",
    "decryptConfig": "node_modules/.bin/coffee config/decrypt.coffee",
    "postinstall": "npm run decryptConfig"
  },
```

The `npm install` seems to work. But the `postinstall` does not execute. Is this a known issue? If so, how can I execute something post `npm install` but before `npm start`?

Answer (score 10):

I've just come across this problem too. I found that a `postinstall` script would not run but a `prestart` would. Mine looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "prestart": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
}
```

That now correctly bundles my webpack stuff before starting the server when I run `eb deploy` locally.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant that you are using EB (Elastic Beanstalk) ELB being the load balancer. 
Elastic Beanstalk is running `npm start` by default to run your application. 
I recommend you to package your modules with your application in your build process.